# Making rollover between 2 images by hover

Tags: css, reactjs, image, hover, rollover

I'm using React and try to change 2 images by hovering them.
This is what I have done so far:

Card.js

```
<div className="image-wrapper">
    <img src={sprites.front_default} className="image" alt="normal" />
    <img src={sprites.back_default} className="image-hover" alt="hover" />
  </div>
```

style.css

```
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
.image-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**The main problem is that i want to make the front image opacity to 0 when im hovering the div, how can i make it?**

I can make it without the fade changing but its important to make it with transition.
This is how I make it without transition

```
<img
        className="figure"
        src={sprites.front_default}
        onMouseOver={(e) => (e.currentTarget.src = sprites.back_default)}
        onMouseOut={(e) => (e.currentTarget.src = sprites.front_default)}
        alt={"pokemon"}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just HTML & CSS. In the Card:

```
<div className="image-wrapper">
  <img
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png"
    className="pokemon-image"
    alt="normal"
  />
  <img
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/2.png"
    className="pokemon-image pokemon-image--back"
    alt="normal"
  />
</div>
```

Here, I've used one class `pokemon-image` to position the two images at the center of the `image-wrapper` element, and `pokemon-image--back` as the class that is showed when hovering over the `image-wrapper` element.

The CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
}

.pokemon-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.pokemon-image--back {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.image-wrapper:hover .pokemon-image--back {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps. You can try it in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-image-transition-onhover-79os1).